# Convert epoch to local time in perl on windows

Tags: windows, perl, epoch

We are trying to convert the output received from the below code

The current output is in this form

```
testingwindows,1446727960,1446728560,kkulka11,testingwin
testingwindows1,1446727160,141228560,kkulka11,testingwin
testingwindows2,1446727120,1446728560,kkulka11,testingwin
testingwindows3,1446727960,1446728560,kkulka11,testingwin
```

The output required is something like

```
testingwindows from Fri Oct  3 13:51:05 2015 GMT to Mon Nov  9 13:51:05 2015 GMT by kkulka11 for testingwin.
testingwindows1 from Fri Oct 2 13:51:05 2015 GMT to Mon Nov  9 13:51:05 2015 GMT by kkulka11 for testingwin.
testingwindows2 from Fri Oct 2 13:51:05 2015 GMT to Mon Nov  9 13:51:05 2015 GMT by kkulka11 for testingwin.
testingwindows3 from Fri Oct 12 13:51:05 2015 GMT to Mon Nov  9 13:51:05 2015 GMT by kkulka11 for testingwin.
```

This is my current code

```
if ( $COMMAND eq 'queryone' ) {
    my $msend_query = "$MCELL_HOME\\bin\\mquery";
    my @args_query = (
        $msend_query,
        "-q",
        "-c", "$MCELL_HOME\\etc\\mclient.conf",
        "-n", "$CS_BLACKOUT_CELL",
        "-d",
        "-f", "csv",
        "-a", "CS_EMB_GBF_BLACKOUTS" ,
        "-s", "blackout_host,start_timestamp,stop_timestamp,userid,reason",
        "-w", "blackout_host: == '${BLACKOUTHOST}'"
    );
    system(@args_query);
```

We tried using  `perl -pe 's/(\d{10})/gmtime($1)/e';` but not able to convert and it gives this error

> 'o~}go⌂⌂t⌂x⌂w' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

when we used the code as

```
if ( $COMMAND eq 'queryone' ) {
    my $msend_query = "$MCELL_HOME\\bin\\mquery";
    my $mqt = "$MCELL_HOME\\mqt.pl";
    my @args_query = (
        $msend_query,
        "-q",
        "-c", "$MCELL_HOME\\etc\\mclient.conf",
        "-n", "$CS_BLACKOUT_CELL",
        "-d",
        "-f", "csv",
        "-a", "CS_EMB_GBF_BLACKOUTS",
        "-s", "blackout_host,start_timestamp,stop_timestamp,userid,reason",
        "-w", "blackout_host: == '${BLACKOUTHOST}'"
    ) | $mqt;
    system(@args_query);
```

Needed experts quick help and guidance to achieve the output in human-readable format.

**Edit:**

Updated  the code as per Jacob comments but still not received the output as desired. Please suggest

```
if ( $COMMAND eq 'queryone' ) {
    my $msend_query = "$MCELL_HOME\\bin\\mquery";
    my @args_query = (
        $msend_query,
        "-q",
        "-c", "$MCELL_HOME\\etc\\mclient.conf",
        "-n", "$CS_BLACKOUT_CELL",
        "-d",
        "-f", "csv",
        "-a", "CS_EMB_GBF_BLACKOUTS" ,
        "-s", "blackout_host,start_timestamp,stop_timestamp,userid,reason",
        "-w", "blackout_host: == '${BLACKOUTHOST}'"
    );
    chomp;
    my @parts = split(/,/, system(@args_query));
    $parts[1] = localtime($parts[1]);
    $parts[2] = localtime($parts[2]);
    printf("%s from %s to %s by %s for %s\n", @parts);
}
```

Output:

```
M:\AbhayBackup\PerlKK>test.pl -q -h testingwin
testingwin
sub: testingwin
testingwin,1446727960,1446728560,kkulka11,testingwin
0 from Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970 to Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970 by  for
```

Comment: `... ) | $mqt;` - you're doing a bitwise OR of your command string. This makes no sense.

Comment: @melpomene .. suggest what we may do to correct the same .
In Unix script we did using perl -pe in the mqt.pl and prnted the output using awk -F but in windows same does not work ..hence needed your suggestions

Comment: "Correct" how? I have no idea what your code is trying to do there. Why did you put bitwise operations in there in the first place?

Comment: Our code is pulling five values blackout_host,start_timestamp,stop_timestamp,userid,reason from some flat files
in which start_timestamp and start_timestamp time are in epoch and we want to convert it human readable and get the same printed

Comment: I don't think you understand what your code is doing.

Comment: elif [[ "${COMMAND}" == 'queryOne' ]]
then
    if [[ "${BLACKOUTHOST}" == '' ]]
    then
       blackout_usage
       exit 1
    fi

    ${MCELL_BIN}/mquery -q -c ${MCELL_ETC}/mclient.conf \
                             -n "${CS_BLACKOUT_CELL}" -d -f 'csv' \
                             -a 'CS_EMB_GBF_BLACKOUTS' \ blackout_host,start_timestamp,stop_timestamp,userid,reason' \
                             -w "blackout_host: == '${BLACKOUTHOST}'" | $MCELL_HOME/mqt.pl |awk -F ',' ' { print $1,echo "from " $2 echo " GMT",echo "to "$3 echo " GMT",echo "by " $4,echo "for " $5 }'\

Comment: @Newbie What is that supposed to be?

Comment: @Matt Jacob by your code we are getting 
testwin1,1446997690,1446998590,kkulka11,testing
testwin1,1446997892,1446998792,kkulka111,testing
15 from  to Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970 by Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970 for

Comment: @Matt Jacob output should be exactly s that of yours but we are getting above ..

Comment: Then you either didn't copy and paste correctly, or your input isn't what you said it is. You can see the complete input and output in my answer!

Comment: The issue that msend_query gives some outeverytime , now how I am getting that print is a query .What should I placed in my _DATA_ value in your logic

Comment: You're creating a file, yes? Now you need to open that file, iterate over it line by line, and apply my logic to it, and everything will work. The `__DATA__` section is just for creating a self-contained example. Swap out `<DATA>` with your actual filehandle (you're opening a file, remember?) and then Bob's your uncle.

Comment: You'll probably also want to order [this book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1449303587) and choose overnight delivery at checkout.

Answer (score -1):

```
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    my @parts = split(/,/, $_);
    $parts[1] = localtime($parts[1]);
    $parts[2] = localtime($parts[2]);

    printf("%s from %s to %s by %s for %s\n", @parts);
}

__DATA__
testingwindows,1446727960,1446728560,kkulka11,testingwin
testingwindows1,1446727160,141228560,kkulka11,testingwin
testingwindows2,1446727120,1446728560,kkulka11,testingwin
testingwindows3,1446727960,1446728560,kkulka11,testingwin
```

Output:

```
testingwindows from Thu Nov  5 05:52:40 2015 to Thu Nov  5 06:02:40 2015 by kkulka11 for testingwin
testingwindows1 from Thu Nov  5 05:39:20 2015 to Sun Jun 23 07:09:20 1974 by kkulka11 for testingwin
testingwindows2 from Thu Nov  5 05:38:40 2015 to Thu Nov  5 06:02:40 2015 by kkulka11 for testingwin
testingwindows3 from Thu Nov  5 05:52:40 2015 to Thu Nov  5 06:02:40 2015 by kkulka11 for testingwin
```

---

Edit: based on your most recent update to the question, I now believe that you're trying to capture the output of the command and process it. Since you haven't provided a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and because I have no idea what `mquery` is and you haven't provided an explanation for that, either, I present to you this guess:

```
if ($COMMAND eq 'queryone') {
    my @lines = `$MCELL_HOME\\bin\\mquery -q -c $MCELL_HOME\\etc\\mclient.conf -n $CS_BLACKOUT_CELL -d -f csv -a CS_EMB_GBF_BLACKOUTS -s blackout_host,start_timestamp,stop_timestamp,userid,reason -w blackout_host: == '${BLACKOUTHOST}'`;

    for (@lines) {
        chomp;

        my @parts = split(/,/, $_);
        $parts[1] = localtime($parts[1]);
        $parts[2] = localtime($parts[2]);

        printf("%s from %s to %s by %s for %s\n", @parts);
    }       
}
```

Comment: the request was for the timezone abbr to be in the output too

Comment: @ysth Good point. He also said "local time" in the subject and then used `gmtime()` in his code, so I really don't have any idea what he wants.

Comment: @MattJacob Your output is correct and we need it in similar manner but not sure where we are doing a mistake so it is not coming as desired

Comment: Well, I'm not sure either. Maybe you should edit your question to show what you're doing.

Comment: Updated the Question with results as per your suggestion but still not received as desired